# What does "is for" mean exactly?

Tags: meaning, synonyms, alphabet

I get the main idea in phrases like "L is for the way you look at me" and "A is for Apple", but I don't know the exact meaning.

If you were to use other words instead of "is for" which synonym would you use?
I understand the meaning is slightly different in the above phrases, but can "is for" be replaced with one word or phrase that would work in both cases?

Are there any popular examples with "is for"(like the above line from Frank Sinatra's L.O.V.E), fixed phrases or collocations?

Answer (score 4):

They actually are similar. In both cases a letter is used to "stand in for" (that is, to represent) a word that begins with that letter (L for Look, A for Apple).

So I think a single-word substitute would be "represents".  But that's not as concise or poetic.

Here's a song along those lines:

http://lyricsplayground.com/alpha/songs/m/motherhowardjohnsontheodoremorse.shtml

Comment: And in fact, the [dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/for?q=is+for) agrees with you: "**for** 7. Representing (the thing mentioned):
*the ‘F’ is for Fascinating*"